# Creating layouts with scroll down

Tags: java, android, android-layout

Im kind of new to android programming with java, and theres a small thing which i want to clarify, i have no idea what this is called either and the Question topic name might not match to what im asking here so sorry about that :P

I want to **dynamically create panels** which will get filled with a text, and a button when the user clicks the `small plus sign` (ref image)

Can anyone point me to a tutorial becouse i dont know what this is called, and any small examples would help as well

[image: ![enter image description here]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Db5oR.png)

Comment: It is called a `RecyclerView`. Here is a tutorial https://www.androidhive.info/2016/01/android-working-with-recycler-view/

Comment: You should use a ListView https://www.raywenderlich.com/124438/android-listview-tutorial

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For something really simple based off your design, I might recommend using a `ListView` as the learning curve is easier. However, the `RecyclerView` is optimized for performance and can be easier to build a lot more crazy scrollable layouts such as Instagram.

Recyclerview Tutorial in Kotlin by Ray Wanderlich -
https://www.raywenderlich.com/170075/android-recyclerview-tutorial-kotlin

Android Documentation - Recyclerview - 
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.html
https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/recyclerview.html

Android Documentation - Listview - 
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html
https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/listview.html

Vogell ListView Tutorial - 
http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidListView/article.html